# PayPal popup issue: When I click "pay with PayPal" the window pops up for split second and then vanishes

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, paypal, paypal-express

When I click "pay with PayPal" in a new browser for the first time the window pops up for split second and then vanishes. This error shows only on the cart page.

[image]

It shows this error in the console

ppxo_unhandled_error
Object { stack: "Expected reject to be called with Error, got [object Undefined]\ns</o.reject@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:18759\ne@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:18298\npayment@https://eadn-wc02-4601666.nxedge.io/cdn/static/version1628582722/frontend/americanfireglass/afg/en_US/Magento_Paypal/js/in-context/express-checkout-smart-buttons.min.js:2:621\n@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:835612\ne@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:18140\n@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:835290\ns</e.try@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:21987\ndecorate/<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:818839\nn@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:383051\nb</</<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:127555\ns</e.try@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:21987\nb</<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:127523\nw[l.b.POST_MESSAGE_TYPE.REQUEST]/<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:115516\ns</e.try@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:21987\nw[l.b.POST_MESSAGE_TYPE.REQUEST]@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:115218\nL@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:117244\n_@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:117488\n\nw[l.b.POST_MESSAGE_TYPE.RESPONSE]@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:116347\nL@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:117244\n_@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:117488\n", errtype: "[object Error]", timestamp: 1628595129658, windowID: "e991eb0d05", pageID: "96c6685782", prev_corr_ids: "", referer: "https://c9df297ea0.nxcli.net", host: "www.sandbox.paypal.com", path: "/smart/button", env: "sandbox", … }
logger.js:63:34
Uncaught Error: Expected reject to be called with Error, got [object Undefined]
s</o.reject@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:18759
e@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:18298
payment@https://eadn-wc02-4601666.nxedge.io/cdn/static/version1628582722/frontend/americanfireglass/afg/en_US/Magento_Paypal/js/in-context/express-checkout-smart-buttons.min.js:2:621
@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:835612
e@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:18140
@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:835290
s</e.try@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:21987
decorate/<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:818839
n@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:383051
b</</<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:127555
s</e.try@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:21987
b</<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:127523
w[l.b.POST_MESSAGE_TYPE.REQUEST]/<@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:115516
s</e.try@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:21987
w[l.b.POST_MESSAGE_TYPE.REQUEST]@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:115218
L@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:117244
_@https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js:2:117488
l.b.POST_MESSAGE_TYPE.RESPONSE types.js:121
L index.js:114
_ index.js:140

[image]

[image: "Console Error"]

Comment: Did you fix it? What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Super late reply:

I've been running into this recently, and I believe you have a conflict between modules.

Try disabling any un-used modules that offer PayPal as a Payment option.

Then run the standard setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, cache:clean.

May want to run `composer update` as well, then rinse & repeat the update process (setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, cache:clean)

I do some Magento use testing regularly, in my test environment I had to disable the following:
Adobe Payments
Bolt Pay
Sparsh PayPal Subscriptions

Once these were disabled, I was immediately able to successfully place payments without issue to PayPal Sandbox using Guest Checkout, PP Credit, PayPal Balance, and Credit Cards from the PayPal Dev Portal CC Generator.

I have not put in the time to determine exactly which module was the cause of the issue.

Hope this helps someone in the future.